# Can't access internet via ad hoc in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, networking, internet, network-manager

I've got very weird situation. 
I have PC with ethernet and wireless. On PC I've created ad hoc network in Ubuntu 14.04, and I'm trying to connect it with my laptop Ubuntu 14.04.

What is weird:

1. When ad hoc has *WEP 40* security setup, I can connect it via laptop
   but I don't have internet access from laptop.
2. When ad hoc has *NONE* security, I can connect it via laptop and I have internet access.
3. When I use *WPA2* security for ad hoc, I can see network name in networks list on my laptop, but it's unclickable( neither can connect via *connect to hidden networks*)

I've already spent 4 hrs investigating first 4 pages of google, but could find anything. 
I don't want to have unsecured network at all, will appreciate any help :)